# Need help to run Cross-browser(Multi Browser) Testing using cucumber,selenium, maven , TestNG in junit run

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, junit, cross-browser, cucumber

**Please see below my codes and help to break my Parentdriver class for multiple drivers. I am tired now.This code run in chrome Properly as junit and maven**

> **Parendriver.java**

```
package com.maxreqman.framework;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public abstract class ParentDriver {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    public  WebDriver getDriver() {

        if (driver == null) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
           "ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");            
            ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            cOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            cOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            cOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
            cOptions.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");
            Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
            prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
            cOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
            cOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Arrays.asList("enable-automation"));
            driver = new ChromeDriver(cOptions);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        }
        return driver;
    }

}
```

> **ParenScenario.java**

```
package com.maxreqman.framework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.maxreqman.pageObject.LogIn;

public class ParentScenario extends ParentDriver {

    protected WebDriver driver = getDriver();

    public LogIn login;

    public void startBrowser() {
        login = new LogIn(driver);
    }

    public void navigateTo() {
          driver.navigate().to("http://www.myurl.com");

    }

}
```

> **LogIn_StepDefinition.java**

```
package com.maxreqman.glue;

import com.maxinvman.framework.ParentScenario;

import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class LogIn_StepDefinitions extends ParentScenario {

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario() throws Throwable {
        startBrowser();
    }

    @Given("^User is on LogIn page$")
    public void user_is_on_LogIn_page() throws Throwable {
        navigateTo();
    }

    @When("^User enters \"([^\"]*)\" into Username field$")
    public void user_enters_into_Username_field(String UName) throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.enterUsername(UName);
    }

    @And("^User enters \"([^\"]*)\" into Password field$")
    public void user_enters_into_Password_field(String Pass) throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.enterPassword(Pass);
    }

    @And("^User Click LogIn button$")
    public void user_Click_LogIn_button() throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.clickButton();
    }

}
```

> **LogIn.java(PageObject)**

```
package com.maxreqman.pageObject;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.maxinvman.framework.ParentDriver;

public class LogIn extends ParentDriver {

    WebDriver driver = getDriver();

    public LogIn(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void enterUsername(String UName) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Username']")).sendKeys(UName);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String Pass) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(Pass);
    }

    public void clickButton() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']/div[5]/button")).click();
    }    
}
```

> **Runner(Junit)**

```
package com.maxreqman.runner;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/Feature_All/1A_LoginValidationCheck/",
        glue = "com.maxreqman.glue",
        plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"},
        format = {"json:target/cucumber.json","html:target/A_Features"}
        )
public class Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @AfterClass
    public static void setup() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/resources/extentreports/extent-config.xml"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Windows 10 Pro");
        Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Max Requisition Managment Testing");
    }   
}
```

> **TestNG XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test Suite">

    <test name="Test Cases Suite">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.maxreqman.runner.Runner"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

> **POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>MAXRequisitionManagement</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MaxReqManTesting</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>

    <plugins>        
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.6.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <source>1.8</source>
           <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
              <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
              <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execution</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <projectName>MaxReqMan</projectName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>browserstack-local-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**1A_LoginValidationCheck.feature**

## Author:Md.Borhan Uddin Sarker,

## Keywords Summary :Requisitions Testing Framework

```
Feature: User Test LogIn

  Scenario: Unsuccessful Login with Invalid Username and Valid Password
    Given User is on LogIn page
    When User enters "mithukhan18@yahoo.com" into Username field
    And User enters "123" into Password field
    And User Click LogIn button
    And Login Denied With Alert Message "Invalid Email or Password"

  Scenario: Unsuccessful Login with Valid Username and Invalid Password
    Given User is on LogIn page
    When User enters "fahadbilla@yahoo.com" into Username field
    And User enters "123d34593234556" into Password field
    And User Click LogIn button
    And Login Denied With Alert Message "Invalid Email or Password"

  Scenario: Unsuccessful Login with Blank Username and Blank Password
    Given User is on LogIn page
    When User enters "" into Username field
    And User enters "" into Password field
    And User Click LogIn button
    And Login Denied With Alert Message "Please enter valid email address"

  Scenario: Unsuccessful Login with Blank Username and Valid Password
    Given User is on LogIn page
    When User enters "" into Username field
    And User enters "123" into Password field
    And User Click LogIn button
    And Login Denied With Alert Message "Please enter valid email address"

  Scenario: Unsuccessful Login with Valid Username and Blank Password
    Given User is on LogIn page
    When User enters "fahadbillah@yahoo.com" into Username field
    And User enters "" into Password field
    And User Click LogIn button
    And Login Denied With Alert Message "Please enter password"

  Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Username and Valid Password
    Given User is on LogIn page
    When User enters "fahadbillah@yahoo.com" into Username field
    And User enters "123" into Password field
    And User Click LogIn button
    And User Login Successfully
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What is error you are seeing? Thanks

Comment: This project is fully up and running...but I can only use single driver(chrome/firefox) at a time. I want to run this with multiple driver and parallel. Pleaee see the parentdriver.java class....can you please help me to convert it to run in multidriver...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add `selenium grid` dependency in your `pom.xml`. The dependency is as follows:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium.grid/selenium-grid-hub -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.grid</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-grid-hub</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

In your script, you'll need to setup `geckodriver` for mozilla and `chromedriver' for chrome browser. Just define the path where the drivers are saved in your machine.